# I Say To myself:"I Am An Engineer!"...How Do I Arrive At That Point?

Tags: robotics, computer-engineering

**"Ponder the path of your feet, and let all your ways be established." Proverbs 4:26**

Over the last two years I have had a strong will to become an inventor within the field of 
computer-technology/robotics,a field where I have many visions and concepts for projects, 
and have been persistent and consistent in my ways, so that I may reach a point that I 
can assume the title of engineer.

I'm currently working full-time(lot's of over-time as a laborer), yet with all my free time I try to mold myself
into the man that can execute these projects I visualized. I'm currently trying to design and develop my first project, and I wasted a lot of time picking different books
up, not knowing where to start my research and discipline.

Should I have started with programming? Electronics? Mechanics? Eventually I realized that I had a strong 
apptitude for mathematics, and decided to order a used college algebra book from online, and I have been making
progress ever since(would be done with the txtbook if it wasn't for the amount of hours I worked every week.)
    Electronics was a path that I always felt was on this path that I am becoming aware of, and in different periods
of my life I would find myself picking up Eectronics books and for reasons beyond my understanding I would never get far.

Yet now that I have developed a solid foundation of mathematics, I am beginning to understand and comprehend Electronics 
theory, and I am confident that I can now begin to progress to tinkering with components. 
    I have also decided that maybe it would be a good thing not to try to discipline myself so much, so I 
have enrolled into a computer science degree program, and my long term educational goal Is to become a computer engineer.

With all this being stated, what is the path? We all have a journey, we all have a point in space-time that we 
have visualized, but how do you arrive at that point? How do I arrive at the point where I have designed and developed 
my first robotics project?

I'm seeking feedback from the community so that I may arrive at this point as efficiently as possible. Thank you.

**P.S.: Excuse me for my lack of formatting, this is only my second post on Stack-Exchange, and it is a learning curve for me.

Comment: I reformatted your post a bit (no changes to the content). To make paragraphs, just enter an empty line. Don't try to indent the start of a paragraph - that may do strange things to the formatting!

Comment: Career and education advice are off-topic for the site.  And a relevant meta post: https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261/are-academic-guidance-questions-on-topic

Comment: You don't say that sort of thing about yourself.  The World should say that about you.

Comment: The world can't define me though. Who made Lebron James a champion? The world? Or he by his will? Who made Thomas Edison an inventor? The world? Or he by his will?

Comment: @IamPyre What would Lebron James' or Thomas Edison's achievements have been without other people to experience them?  Anyone can consider themselves something.  It's getting _everyone else_ to perceive you that way that's the real challenge.

Comment: Diversify and learn a lot of different things. Different different. A lick of chemistry, a bit of aerodynamics, some basics of civil engineering, a bit about food industry, some machining... Once you look at a technical problem in any branch, and can come up with a working (not optimal, but viable) solution withing 5 minutes, you'll be able to say "I am an engineer" with confidence.

Comment: @IamPyre depending on the country you live in you may not be able to publicly call yourself an engineer unless you are officially registered and recognized as one by your local engineering association or chapter. In Canada for example engineering is a legally recognized profession, therefore a person falsely claiming to be an engineer may be sued/told to cease and desist.

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma I believe "Professional Engineer" or "P.Eng." designation is protected.  The term "Engineer" on it's own is not, as there are many types of "Engineer" that don't necessarily require formal education.  That said, a lot of safety requirements need a stamp from a professional engineer on drawings and designs anyways,

Comment: @JMac you're correct that "PEng" is specifically protected, but if you use the term "Engineer" in any way that implies "Professional Engineer" status, then you open yourself to a lawsuit. In my province the local Association has gone after people for that reason before

Comment: @BarbalatsDilemma Depends on what you're doing.  If you try and suggest something is safe or well made because "I'm an engineer!" without any certification; you're probably gonna be in trouble.  That said, I don't think there are protections on being a "network engineer" for example.  Trying to pass off work as being done "by an engineer" wouldn't fly;  but it all depends on how you use the term.

Comment: @JMac yeah that's a good way of putting it. If you call yourself an engineer but don't try to open an engineering business or otherwise certify designs you're not going to get in trouble. I just thought it was worth mentioning since the OP seemed to indicate very little knowledge of the engineering profession

Comment: @JMac Illusions you speak of, perception means nothing. If it is the world that defines a man, then God help us. People "perceive" muslims as terrorist, is the Muslim a terrorist? People perceive African Americans as dumb and ignorant? Is the black man so?

Comment: It's a debate of philosophy, which I don't want to further engage in. I believe it's to say that I made a statement, and I'm willing to die behind that statement. I'm willing to work to the highest degree so that my statement is established as truth...

Comment: @JMac It's funny that this conversation takes me back to "The Matrix". You see everything as consequences, I see everything as choices.

Comment: @IamPyre I'm just saying, if Lebron James only played in his backyard, _he_ could consider himself as a legendary basketball player, but no one would have to agree with him.  Thomas Edison could have made things and then kept them a secret, and if he claimed he were an inventor, people would say "Then prove it."  Being a self-proclaimed "anything" is not much of accomplishment.  Getting _others_ to acknowledge you as such requires true demonstration of talent.  Achievement in a vacuum is basically useless.  Achievement for civilization can last a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from a fairly low level academic background, I think the best way to "develop your first robotics project" is to focus on the practical side, not the theory.

Get a robotics kit like Lego Mindstorms, build some of the tutorial projects, then follow your own ideas. Mindstorms is not just a "kid's toy" - MIT were involved in designing it, and it is used at university level for robotics lab work. It has the advantage of providing ready-made *subsystems* that do relevant tasks which you can interconnect to make your complete robot, instead of having to design everything yourself from scratch.

Of course you *can* design your own subsystems from scratch and use them with the rest of the Mindstorms kit, if you need to or want to learn how to do that. But in the real world, engineers don't design stuff from scratch just "because they know how to", if they can buy it ready-made at a reasonable price.

I wouldn't discourage anyone from starting a computer science degree program - so long as you understand that computer science is fundamentally a *theoretical* subject, not a *practical* one. Realistically, your math background might not be strong enough to start a CS course right now. You might do better to switch to computer engineering, or mechatronics - they are more focused on "practical engineering" and actually "making stuff" rather than the theory of "why stuff works" - though of course CE and mechatronics will also cover the *essential* parts of the theory.

Note, "making stuff" in the previous paragraph includes "making software" as well as "making hardware". You probably don't need to know how to design and write your own compiler for a new computer language (which you would learn how to do in a CS course) or design a new type of CPU chip to run your newly invented language efficiently - but you do need to know how to *use* a "standard" programming language and like C, C++ or Java and "standard" embedded computing hardware like an Arduino, a Raspberry Pi, or a smaller microcontroller system to interface with the hardware of your robot. A CE course is likely to be more relevant for that than CS.

The same applies for "learning electronics". Get some (fairly cheap and simple) kits, build them, then modify them. When (note, "when" not "if"!) your modifications don't work, you can always ask why on Electronics SE! The theory will make more sense if it you can relate it to a practical context. Theory on its own is all very well, but the *real* learning starts when  you try to understand what just caused some of your circuit components to "release their magic smoke" and die!

Comment: You mentioned getting involved with"lego mindstorms", that seems pretty outdated, why not get involved with Arduino or Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Hah! I was editing my post to say just that when you made the comment! But just because something is "old" doesn't necessarily mean it's "outdated." The first version of Mindstorms is about 20 years old, but the latest (EV3) version is only 4 years old, which is younger than some variants of the Arduino that are still popular.

Comment: @IamPyre arduions dont give you mechanical parts. A microcontroller is a microcontroller the one inside a lego is far newer than the one used in a arduino uno.

Comment: I've seen lots of "magic smoke" ... haven't found a way to put it back in yet though !

Comment: The trick is to pull the chip out and put the smoke back in from below. No idea how this works for motors though ;P